# Comparing every object in a Map of Lists in Java

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashmap, iterator

I have a Java program with a Map of type `<String, Project>` which contains all Project objects and each object of Project contains a List of related Process objects i.e. `List<Process>`.

```
public class Project {
    private String name;
    private Path path;
    private List<Process> processes;
        \\ getters and setters follow
```

and

```
public class Process {
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private String flow;
        \\getters and setters follow
```

I'm writing a function to find the String distance (using `JaroWinklerDistance`) between `flow` of each `Process` (across all Projects). I came up with the following:

```
    public void compareAllProcesses(Map<String, Project> projects) {
        Iterator<Project> projIter1 = projects.values().iterator();
        while(projIter1.hasNext()) {
            Project proj1 = projIter1.next();
            Iterator<Process> procIter1 = proj1.getProcesses().iterator();
            while(procIter1.hasNext()) {
                Process proc1 = procIter1.next();
                Iterator<Project> projIter2 = projects.values().iterator();
                while(projIter2.hasNext()) {
                    Project proj2 = projIter2.next();
                    Iterator<Process> procIter2 = proj2.getProcesses().iterator();
                    while(procIter2.hasNext()) {
                        Process proc2 = procIter2.next();
                        //use JaroWinklerDistance to compare proc1.getFlow() with proc2.getFLow()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a more efficient and elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by compare? what do you want to achieve from comparison?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994021/compare-every-item-to-every-other-item-in-arraylist

Comment: @Kartik I've edited my post to specify the comparison I wish to do

Comment: Are you sure you really want to compare every process with every other process? Performance of that gonna be really bad. For 10 projects with 10 processes each thats gonna be 10k comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps with `Stream`s:

```
projects.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(p->p.getProcesses().stream())
        .forEach(proc1 ->  projects.values()
                                   .stream()
                                   .flatMap(p->p.getProcesses().stream())
                                   .forEach(proc2 -> {/*do something with proc1 and proc2*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little sugar perhaps:

```
    for (Project proj1: projects.values()) {
        for (Process proc1: proj1.getProcesses()) {
            for(Project proj2: projects.values()) {
                for(Process proc2: proj2.getProcesses()) {
                    //use JaroWinklerDistance to compare proc1.getFlow() with proc2.getFLow()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Process> allProcesses = projects.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(p->p.getProcesses().stream());

for (Process currentProcess : allProcesses) {
    for (Process process : allProcesses) {
        //distance calculation
    }
}
```